# Autocad .Net API entities constructors, drawing like in AutoLisp

Tags: c#, .net, autocad

I want to draw lines, circles, arcs and other standard entities in c# like in AutoLisp. E.g. in AutoLisp you can draw circles via 3 points on its circumference. But in .Net API there is only constructor via center and radius. So if I have 3 point on circumference I have to calculate the center and radius the same way it makes Autocad. So I have to copy the logic already exists. Is there any libs doing that or maybe I miss something?
And I need 20 reputation to get access to chat ><

Answer (score 2):

You can create an instance of the non database resident type: Autodesk.AutoCAD.Geometry.CircularArc3d which has a 3 points constructor.

If you need to add a Circle object to the database, you can use the CircularArc3d Center, Normal and Radius properties to create the Circle instance.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this situation while developing my ARX applications.
In ARX I use acedCmd and acedCommand. I suppose it will be easiest way.

[sample You can find here](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/04/synchronously-send-and-wait-for-commands-in-autocad-using-c-net.html)

Comment: Since AutoCAD 2015, you don't need anymore to P/Invoke acedCmd(), you can call Editor.Command() and Editor.CommandAsync() method.
http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2014/03/autocad-2015-calling-commands.html